# How to see arguments when creating a new class?

Tags: intellij-idea

When creating a new class or method I used to be able to see the parameters needed. But, now they don't come up anymore. How do I view parameters when creating a class?

Running the latest windows version.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Case theCase = new Case("Default", "Corsair", "500W");
    }
}

public class Case {

    private String model;
    private String manufacturer;
    private String powerSupply;

    public Case(String model, String manufacturer, String powerSupply,) {
       this.model = model;
       this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
       this.powerSupply = powerSupply;

    }

    public void pressPowerButton() {
        System.out.println("Power button pressed");
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public String getPowerSupply() {
        return powerSupply;
    }
}
```

When making theCase I can't see what my parameters are and have to move to the "Case" class back and forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly call `Parameter Info` action which is usually mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>(Cmd)</kbd> - <kbd>p</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind in order to see the parameters as you type you must type them while in the editor without moving your cursor.

Comment: And Im not sure if ctrl-P can help?